# Excel date to string conversion =TEXT(D35, "yyyy.mm.dd") error : There is a problem with formula

Tags: excel

I would like to convert a date cell to string into another cell, but always get this

[image]

The error is: There's a problem with this formula ...

Thanks for the answers
Csaba

Comment: Change the comma to semicolon `;` or use the appropriate separator as per your `regional settings`

Comment: you are right the error is gone, but the result is: 'yyyy.00.dd' for date '2023.05.05' and the error how misleading, changing the function parameter separator based on the regional settings a bit crazy

Comment: not sure about your regional date format settings. may be this one could work --> `eeee.mm.tt` . Also your query is best suited for **[superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)**

Comment: Guy you are right totally, the parameter separator and the date format is also localized, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Mayukh Bhattacharya the answer is:

the parameter separator and date format must be in a localized format.

I have to use `;` and `eeee.hh.nn` for them.

```
=TEXT(D35; "eeee.hh.nn")
```

Comment: you can consider accepting your answer so its closed and helps someone in future.